# Assigning value of element to the variable output

Tags: python, list, variables, output, element

So, I'm on a beginner's python course on coursera and there is a question I just don't understand:

> Assign the value of the 34th element of `lst` to the variable `output`.

Here is the list:

```
1st = ["hi", "morning", "dog", "506", "caterpillar", "balloons", 106, "yo-yo", "python",
       "moon", "water", "sleepy", "daffy", 45, "donald", "whiteboard", "glasses",
       "markers", "couches", "butterfly", "100", "magazine", "door", "picture", "window",
       ["Olympics", "handle"], "chair", "pages", "readings", "burger", "juggle", "craft",
       ["store", "poster", "board"], "laptop", "computer", "plates", "hotdog", "salad",
       "backpack", "zipper", "ring", "watch", "finger", "bags", "boxes", "pods", "peas",
       "apples", "horse", "guinea pig", "bowl", "EECS"]
```

What am I supposed to do with this thing? I'm not looking for anyone to straight up give me the answer, but rather help me understand what the question wants from me and how to solve it.

Comment: The question is asking you to assign (`=`) the 34th element of `lst` (`lst[33]`, because lists are 0-indexed) to a variable called `output`.  All together that's `output = lst[33]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = 1st[34]
```

"So this is what it says,by indexing the list, you get the value and assign it to the variable output"

Answer (score 0):

The indexing of the list starts from 0.
Therefore, to access the 34th element in the list, you need to enter the index `33`.
The code should then be like this:

```
1st = ["hi", "morning", "dog", "506", "caterpillar", "balloons", 106, "yo-yo", "python",
       "moon", "water", "sleepy", "daffy", 45, "donald", "whiteboard", "glasses",
       "markers", "couches", "butterfly", "100", "magazine", "door", "picture", "window",
       ["Olympics", "handle"], "chair", "pages", "readings", "burger", "juggle", "craft",
       ["store", "poster", "board"], "laptop", "computer", "plates", "hotdog", "salad",
       "backpack", "zipper", "ring", "watch", "finger", "bags", "boxes", "pods", "peas",
       "apples", "horse", "guinea pig", "bowl", "EECS"];
output = lst[33];
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to access any last element in list should be

end_elem =lst[-1]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To index a list, the correct syntax is:

`list[i]` where the `i` is the index of the element you want to retrieve. So in your case:

`output = 1st[34]`

Good luck with Corsera!

Answer (score -1):

yeah. i ended up figuring it out on my own. but a big thanks to both of you, regardless.

so yeah, I did this (in case anyone else ever gets stuck on something like that as well):

## you need to find index 34 because python is 0 index

## output of that will be "laptop"

```
print(lst[34])
```

## now you need to assign the value "laptop" (35th element) to the variable "output"

## which looks like:

```
output = "laptop"
print(output)
```

Comment: Try to format the answer with better Titles and Subtitles, it's not a good practice to use H1 or # (Biggest heading possible) for every line that you think is Important.